# Getting views data as a REST service

Tags: theming, 8, services

I need a way to get the output of a view as a REST service in JSON format.

I read about the RestfulWS and the Services modules, but I didn't find enough documentation.
Are these straight forward, or should I just go with a custom module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps [Services Views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views) module could be of interest here:

> Views support for the Services module version 3.x and later.
>
> It has currently two features:
>   - Create view based resource creating Services display in a view
>   - Execute any view of the system via views resource call
>
> After enabling "views" resource in your services endpoint you can do
>   GET request to:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/<endpoint path>/views/<view name>
> ```
>
> This will execute a view and pass results.